# Footer overflowing into container above

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4. I have a footer container and a contact-us container directly above.  The site renders perfectly in the Firefox Browser but when I try it in Chrome, the footer and the contact-us containers overlap while on XS screen size.

Any idea why this might be?

Thanks.

```
<!-- Footer -->
<section id="footer">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6 text-center p-4">
            <div class="copyright">
                &copy; Copyright <strong>Arcane Defense</strong>.<br>All 
Rights Reserved. <br> Website designed by InnoDesigns.
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Footer Links -->
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <nav class="text-center">
                <a href="#intro">Home</a>
                <a href="#about-us">About</a>
                <a href="#training">Academy</a>
                <a href="#products">Products</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<!-- End Footer -->
```

Comment: you should provide your relevant code samples in a snippet, a link a site, etc.

Comment: Please add some code. Its impossible to help you with only this information

Comment: innodesigns.epizy.com